# What will part of db be load in memory when i do request?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I plan to add a big local database to my application. What part of the db will be loaded in memory when I do the request? All tables from the DB or only the table that I request?

Comment: What is your *problem*? You generally don't have to worry about sqlite's memory management.

Comment: I want to know call in same problem like outOfMemory or no in any way. if yes i save data in files at storage and will work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to worry about memory usage when using sqlite.
you can choose what data you want to access with a **Cursor**. that way you can access a specific table if you want, and get only it's data.

example:

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,null);
c.moveToFirst();
```

this is a way to get a specific table's data.